# Can't get WPF tree items to be recognized despite being visible in Pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Downloaded pywinauto 6.4 using 64 bit python.

I got this code to work once... I left the whole interpreter session in notepad++. I came back to retrace my steps and now I can't get what was already working to work. Why can't I interact with the tree item? It worked the other day but now I can't seem to "see" any of the items in the tree even though they show up with print_control_identifiers()

It's a WPF application I connected to it after it was already open using:

```
>>> import pywinauto
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
>>> app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=".*POS UI", class_name="Window")
>>> app.POS_UI.draw_outline()


    >>> dlg_Xtree1.print_control_identifiers()
Control Identifiers:

TreeView - 'POS_IntranetAPP_Tree1'    (L-839, T-1164, R-643, B-925)
['TreeView', 'POS_IntranetAPP_Tree1TreeView', 'POS_IntranetAPP_Tree1']
child_window(title="POS_IntranetAPP_Tree1", auto_id="POS_IntranetAPP_Tree1", control_type="Tree")
   |
   | TreeItem - 'POS.Tree.Thing. '    (L-838, T-1163, R-707, B-1141)
   | ['TreeItem', 'POS.Tree.Thing. ', 'POS.Tree.Thing. TreeItem', 'TreeItem0', 'TreeItem1', 'POS.Tree.Thing. 0', 'POS.Tree.Thing. 1', 'POS.Tree.Thing. TreeItem0', 'POS.Tree.Thing. TreeItem1']
   | child_window(title="POS.Tree.Thing. ", control_type="TreeItem")
   |
   | TreeItem - 'POS.Tree.Thing. '    (L-838, T-1141, R-701, B-1119)
   | ['TreeItem2', 'POS.Tree.Thing. 2', 'POS.Tree.Thing. TreeItem2']
   | child_window(title="POS.Tree.Thing. ", control_type="TreeItem")
   |
   | TreeItem - 'POS.Tree.Thing. '    (L-838, T-1119, R-679, B-1097)
   | ['TreeItem3', 'POS.Tree.Thing. 3', 'POS.Tree.Thing. TreeItem3']
   | child_window(title="POS.Tree.Thing. ", control_type="TreeItem")



>>> dlg_Xtree1.treeitem2.expand 
<bound method UIAWrapper.expand of <uia_controls.TreeItemWrapper - 
'POS.Tree.Thing', TreeItem,
```

However now, even though it can see the "tree view" it's completely blind to the tree items. I tried reconnecting to the app thinking it might just not be refreshed. I just don't get it... It worked once but now no matter what I do I can't get it to function.

`>>> dlg_Xtree1.TreeItem3.draw_outline()`
`pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'TreeItem3' in 'dict_keys([])'`

So Strangely, after I expanded the menu manually, I could then expand and collapse the same menu without changing my code at all. I'm not sure what that means or how to get around it.

Haha I went to test my hypothesis by closing everything and reopening back up and now I can't get it to work again. :(

Okay so now it seems like in order to bring that "window" to life you have to interact with the other controls. It's visible in inspect.exe and pywinauto can see it with print_control_identifiers() but can't interact with it.

Comment: If you use connect(), always think about running script as Administrator. That might be a reason. With start() the child process has usually the same privilege level and the problem doesn’t exist. I’m working on warnings for these cases for future releases.

Comment: Thank You so much for the quick response! I've seen your answers all over SO, really appreciate your dedication. I'll give this a try.

Comment: This worked! Now I'm getting another strange behavior on the child of the first tree. When I interact with it, it cycles through all the other elements shown activating their popups before finally executing the click() on the element I specified. It goes through the other elements twice before executing the requested action.

Comment: OK, adding the first comment as an answer. Sorry, I didn't get the second issue. Can you describe it in more details as a separate question? How did you get the tree item before calling `click()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `connect()`, always think about running script as Administrator. That might be a reason. With `start()` the child process has usually the same privilege level and the problem doesn’t exist.